# Visual Studio randomly removes class names from my files

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio

Sometimes I am editing a ascx control, and then its working and its compiling, but then when i go to check in the designer class file for that ascx file is now missing its class name, despite me not having edited said file.

Any thoughts why?

Comment: Are you editing `<asp:HiddenField .... />` etc front end controls and then it does not update the designer?

Comment: What do you mean "missing its class name"? can you post your code?

Comment: I mean the designer file's content literally becomes 
'public partial class{}'